# NullPointerExcepcion with Robolectric on Activity.onCreate()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, junit4, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric to test an Activity (FooActivity) that extends BaseActivity and BaseActivity is extending Activity, but I'm getting a NullPointerException in Activity.onCreate()

**FooActivity.java** extends **BaseActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
}
```

**BaseActivity.java** extends **Activity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    this.mActivityCreated = true;
    mFragmentMgr = getFragmentManager();
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

**Test: FooActivityTest**

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    mActivity = new FooActivity();
}


@Test
public void test() {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("isTesting", true);
    mActivity.setIntent(i);
    mActivity.onCreate(null);
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:874)
at com.pdi.enjoy.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:129)
at com.pdi.enjoy.activities.FooActivityTest.onCreate(FooActivity.java:107)
at com.pdi.enjoy.activities.FooActivityTest.test(FooActivity.java:32)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:234)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: we could really use line numbers in the code fragments, this way we can compare it to the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Intent i= new Intent(Robolectric.application, FooActivity.class);
i.putExtra("isTesting", true);

FooActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FooActivity.class).withIntent(i).create().get();
```

Don't manually call onCreate on the activity. Robolectric will take care of that..

From here you can do whatever other tests using the activity object you need.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an earlier version of Robolectric required you to call the lifecycle methods explicitly, but the later ones are able to handle the lifecycle calls themselves.

Also, one had to use `activity.getApplication()` to get the application, but it looks like `Robolectric.application` is directly available now.

@dymmeh: Thanks for you answer.